# How to save other people's Facebook wall? (for a lawsuit)

Tags: facebook

What are the best methods to save other people's Facebook Wall?

Someone is saying bad things about our firm on their wall. We want to collect evidence so that we can file a lawsuit.

Comment: It would be best to consult a lawyer about what sort of evidence is admissible in court and how you would prove to the satisfaction of the court that your material was a true representation and could not have been subsequently altered in any way.

Answer (score 5):

In order to have the posts in context, with the Facebook look of their wall, just take a screen shot. Press the print screen key (upper left on the keyboard). This places a screen shot to the clipboard. Then you can use your editor of preference to paste and save the image. Some people open Word and paste several images into a document to be saved together.

Comment: too many wall posts

Comment: Actually, this may be the best answer.  Yes, there may be a a lot of posts made by this individual, but taking screen shots gives the full layout and appears and is most likely easier to file as evidence.  Even if you have to sort through what would seem like an unreasonable amount of Facebook pages (1000+) screenshots are actually probably the best option that you have.  If you want to sue some one, then you have a very serious problem.  Take the time (even if it's a full 8 hour day) to collect all the evidence you can.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to simply save your friends wall posts, check out [Archivedbook](http://archivedbook.com/). This app shows all posts from a user on a single page. So you can just copy-paste posts from there to wherever you want.

Update: Initially when I answered, lawsuit was not mentioned. In such a case, I'd say screenshots are the best option.

Comment: can someone confirm that this is working? i can't log in to facebook right now

Comment: usaully external apps, even if supposed to be secure, are not intended to be judged as a proof... there is an uncertified extraction software underneath ... you cannot know about all the action that it can take and if it will be able to manipulate the writings extracted... there should be NO WAY that a lawyer will consider it lika a proof if he's a lil bit in matter. The only reasonably cheap way to acquire it is to take a screen shot... eventually in a row format ... with all the timing and system information saved in it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way, and maybe suitable for court, is PRINT the page to an physical printer AND an PDF printer driver (as pdfcreator from sourceforge).
The print made by the browser includes also header and footer with date/time and the complete url.
Maybe best way is print it to landscape (not portrait), this way the url can be complete, also can help change to an small font before to print.